# Finding a basis of subspace $\mathrm{span}(1,4x+3, 3x-4, x^2+2, x - x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

$sp(1,4x+3, 3x-4, x^2+2, x - x^2)$

My attempt

To be a basis in general I need to show the set of vectors span V and they are linearly independent.

Since a basis for $P_2$ is $\{1, x, x^2\}$ we know that $dim(P_2) = 3$ so the given set of five polynomials must be dependent and I need to change that. In otherwords I have to remove two of these vectors.

This is where I'm lost. I don't know how to figure out which to delete to form a basis for this subspace

Comment: You may add the elements of your family one by one to the basis or not, depending on whether they are already in the span of the previous elements or not. In your case, you keep $1$ in the basis because it is not zero, you keep $4x+3$ in the basis because $4x+3$ is not in the span of $(1)$, you leave $3x-4$ because $3x-4$ is in the span of $(1,4x+3)$, and so on until $x-x^2$.

Comment: ((Oh, and your title was absurd, I believe. Now modified.))

Comment: $\{1,4x+3,x^2+2\}$ would work?

Comment: **Tell me!** $ $

Comment: Yes I get a linearly independent set of vector but I am a bit confuse by this. Lets say the question was $\{x^2-1, x^2+1, 4, 2x-3\}$. $x^2-1$ has no previous so it stays. Leave $x^2+1$ because its in the span of the previous $(x^2 - 1)$. keep $4$ because its not in the span of the previous and also keep $2x-3$ because its not in the span of the previous. I get $\{x^2-1, 4, 2x-3\}$. The textbook got $\{x^2-1, x^2+1, 2x-3\}$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Keep $x^2+1$ because it is not in the span of $(x^2-1)$ (which is just another way of saying that $(x^2-1,x^2+1)$ is free). (So, the book is indeed using the leave-or-keep approach...)

Comment: You need to remove *at least* two vectors. How do you know that the span is three-dimensions before investigating further?

Comment: Hmm. I misunderstood span then, I thought it was when they have the same highest degree. What is span?

Comment: Indeed you must **at once** check the definition of the span...

Comment: Okay I get it completely! Thank you very much.